# How to save button state

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have 4 buttons in my detail viewcontroller that push to the same view controller with different data. My problem is,as a beginner, i really don’t know how to save button state for every item.

Here is the code for one of my buttons

```
 @IBAction func addToWatchlistButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: K.ViewControllerName.signupVC) as! SignUpViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else {
            sender.isSelected = !addToWatchlistButton.isSelected
            if addToWatchlistButton.isSelected {
                addToWatchlist()
                print("selected")
                self.addToWatchlistButton.backgroundColor = .clear
                    self.addToWatchlistButton.tintColor = .clear
                    self.addToWatchlistButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: K.UIColors.label), for: .selected)
                    self.addToWatchlistButton.setTitle("Added to Watchlist", for: .selected)
                    self.addToWatchlistButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
                    self.addToWatchlistButton.layer.borderColor = CGColor(srgbRed: 251/255, green: 172/255, blue: 14/255, alpha: 1)
            }else {
                removeFromWatchlist()
                print("deselected")
                self.addToWatchlistButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: K.UIColors.button)
            self.addToWatchlistButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: K.UIColors.label)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "button state"?

Comment: @jshapy8 When button pressed, i want to save that and change button appearance -based on isSelected method - for that movie so when user revisit the same movie page,button need to be set to its latest state.  My question is how can i do that for every different movie.